# iOS Table view cells with transparent background

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

is it possible to make a table look like messages on iPhone. So that maybe each message is a table section with an image of a bubble and on top of that bubble is a label with the message text. Can a table cell be entirely transparent so that only the bubble image is displayed without the white cell, and the border?
Thanks

Comment: Too many questions asked into one :) It is clearly possible what you are asking. Mostly you will find all the answers to your questions on this site.

Comment: Check out this library - http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/uibubbletableview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this :

[UIBubbleTableView](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/uibubbletableview)

If you want the growing textView where you type the message, this is the one :

[HPGrowingTextView](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/hpgrowingtextview)

Answer (score 0):

When you create your cell you can make the background transparant:

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

You can simply add an imageView as backgroundView.